# Max Password Length

Tags: php, hash, passwords, maxlength

Since heartbleed came out I have been changing my passwords but typically whenever I try to improve my password the dreaded "Max Password Length" hits me. This got me wondering, why do many websites force passwords to be less than 20 characters long then try to force you to use a mix of symbols, numbers, and upper/lower. Having a 40 character long sentence with a little creative grammar seems like a much better way to secure your passwords.

I use PHP and typically allow 64+ length passwords without any problems. Is there any programming reason why many websites are still stuck on using less than 20 characters for their passwords?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths

Comment: No, there are no reasons to restrict the length of passwords. The only sensible restriction on passwords should be a minimum length.